# Antlr keywords as identifiers behavior

Tags: antlr, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

In ANTLR, to allow keywords (e.g. var) as identifiers, we can create a parser rule `identifier` like:

```
fieldDeclaration: VAR identifier '=' NUMBER;
identifier: IDENTIFIER | VAR;

VAR: 'var' // keyword;
IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z]+;
NUMBER: [1-9] [0-9]*;
```

and this would allow: `var var = 5`

But if the grammar looks like this instead to change `identifier` slightly:

```
fieldDeclaration: VAR identifier '=' NUMBER;
identifier: IDENTIFIER // *** NOT EXPLICITLY SPECIFYING KEYWORD HERE

VAR: 'var' // keyword;
IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z]+;
NUMBER: [1-9] [0-9]*;
```

then ANTLR will throw an error for `var var = 5` due to the second `var`.

Why does the first example work, but the second example doesn't? It seems that `IDENTIFIER` should already cover `var` as an identifier due to the expression `[a-zA-Z]+`.

Comment: The problem is that you are misunderstanding how Antlr lexers work. Tokenization is never directed by the parser rule. Think of it as the Antlr lexer getting all tokens before the parser ever gets started. Antlr lexers follow two rules: (1) The longest string is matched by a lexer rule first. (2) If the string is matched by two or more lexer rules, the first rule listed "wins". In your example, `var` is always matched by `VAR: 'var';` even though `var` is also matched by `IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z]+;` (because the first rule "wins").

Comment: @kaby76 Thanks. So it seems it's really always choosing the VAR lexer rule in either example. And the `identifier` parser rule in the first example allows "VAR" to be chosen, making `var var = 5` follow the `fieldDeclaration` parser rule in that example. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct @detcle